# Unity - Video codec for older mobile devices

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, video, codec, mobile-devices

I am searching for a video codec for Unity that will run on older mobile devices. I have tried H264 and VP8, but I have not been successful. Below IOS 10 is where I experience the issue. Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: read [ask]. It looks like you're asking for code and SO is not a code-sharing service. You need to have tried something and proven that you tried something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When outputting the H.264 video, set the `Profile` to **Baseline** in your encoding software. This will make it compatible with older devices.